# Как найти строчку в списке списка

Tags: python, список

Моя sql функция возвращает мне список кортежей. Пример: `result = [('p',), ('a',)]`. Мне нужно в одну строчку проверить содержится ли в данном списке данных строчка, условно говоря, 'p'. Если использовать 'p' in result, выдает False т.к. он видит только два кортежа внутри. Как красиво и лаконично решить проблему?

Comment: `[x for x in res for y in x if "p" in y]` - выведет кортежи, в которых есть "p"

Answer (score 3):

я вот такое нагородил:

```
bool(sum([int("p" in el) for el in result]))
```

`int("p" in el)` - ставит 1, если "p" есть в кортеже, 0, если нет.

`sum` - считает итоговую сумму.

`bool` - выдает True, если сумма не 0 (т.е. хотя бы один кортеж содержал "p").

Можно убрать `bool()`, тогда выдаст количество кортежей, которые содержат искомое.

Comment: Простое правило: если вам приходится использовать `bool` в явном виде, значит вы что-то излишне переусложняете ;)  Это записывается проще (и работает быстрее): `any("p" in el for el in result)`. Ну, в случае, если нужен только сам факт наличия. Для подсчёта, понятное дело, без суммы не обойтись (хотя явное приведение к `int` всё-равно излишне).

Comment: @CrazyElf да, точно, про any совсем забыл

Answer (score 0):

можно фильтрануть:

```
bool(*filter(lambda x: x[0]=='p',result))
```